# How to deal with this error?Cast to ObjectId failed for value "new" at path "_id" for model "arms"'

Tags: node.js, mongoose, web-development-server

In arms.js file

```
router.get("/new",middleware.isLoggedIn,function(req,res){
res.render("arms/new");});
```

Below is my new.js file which i think is not causing any error.I think the problem is either in my header1.ejs or especially it is in my mongoose model schema of arms.

```html
<%include ../partials/header1%>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10" offset="md-1">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5 register-left">
            <i class="far fa-hand-point-down"></i>
            <h3>Join Us</h3>
            <p>Sell your weapons here</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">About Us</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7 register-right">
            <h2>Place your Ad</h2>
            <form action="/arms" class="register-form" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="price" placeholder="price" min="0.01" step="0.01">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="url" placeholder="url">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="description">
              </div>

              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit!</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%include ../partials/footer%>
```

here is my header

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Arsenal</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/stylesheets/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/stylesheets/new.css">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                Arms and Ammunition
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/nolan/64/000000/students.png">
        </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <%if(!currentUser){%>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/register">Sign up</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
          </li>
          <%}else{%>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Signed In As <%=currentUser.username%></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Logout</a>
            </li>
            <%}%>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <%if(error && error.length>0){%>
      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <%=error%>
      </div>
      <%}%>
        <%if(success && success.length>0){%>
          <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            <%=success%>
          </div>
          <%}%>
  </div>
```

Well the the real thinn which is bothering me is that I am just sending a get req to this url http://localhost:3000/arms/new and as the above code suggest that whenever a get request is made just render new.ejs which is in folder arms (arms/new) and the i have given u the code of new.ejs which has no relation to mongoose model of arms I m just taking input in form nothing else I have the same code for another project which is working fine butt this is not

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const armSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: String,
  image: String,
  description: String,
  owner: {
    id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User"
    },
    username: String,
  },
  comments: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Comment"
  }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("arms", armSchema);
```

LAST EDIT: I made it actually the problem was that I was trying to make a get request to url arms/new and at the same time I was also handling request which were being sent to arms/:id/... so the problem was that mongoose was expecting :id of type mongoose type objectId which 'new' is obviously not so what I did is that I only placed the code of router.get("arms/new"...) above to the code of arms/:id/... so that whenever some one make a get req to arms/new first this router resolve the response so that it does not go to other routes but whenever a req to arms/mongoose.ObjectId is made then arms/new will fail and the req will go to arms/:id I hope it is clear now but if any of u guys fail do msg me i will resolve ur issue

Comment: This has to do with the _id value that you're passing. Please share you controller code where you have your mongoose/mongoDB queries

Comment: Hm, in regards to how you put your question - would be more readable, if you would put "This is my code": ```code```, and this is an error message: ```error message```. It's good, that SO is suggesting you to put more text there, cause putting error message in the question topic isn't too neat.

Comment: sorry guys for the inconvenience actually  I became out of my mind after finding the solutions for hours. well let me edit post